# Good results when training and cross-validating a model, but test data set shows poor results

Tags: validation, testing, model, scikit-learn

My problem is that I obtain a model with very good results (training and cross-validating), but when I test it again (with a different data set) poor results appear.

I got a model which has been trained and cross-validating tested. The model shows AUC=0.933, TPR=0.90 and FPR=0.04

I guess there is no overfitting present looking at pictures, corresponding to learning curve (error), learning curve (score), and deviance curve:

[image: learning curve with score]
[image: learning curve with error]
[image: deviance curve]

The problem is that when I test this model with a different test data set, I obtain poor results, nothing to do with my previus results AUC=0.52, TPR=0.165 and FPR=0.105

I used Gradient Boosting Classifier to train my model, with learning_rate=0.01, max_depth=12, max_features='auto', min_samples_leaf=3, n_estimators=750

I used SMOTE to balance the class. It is binary model. I vectorized my categorical attributes. I used 75% of my data set to train and 25% tot test. My model has a very low training error, and a low test error, so I guess it is not overfitted. Training error is very low, so there are not outliers in the training and cv-test data sets. What can I do from now on to find the problem? Thanks

Comment: Your model is overfitted to training data. So you have good results during learning phase and poor results on validation data.

Comment: Hi frankov. Why do you think it's overfitted? The CV error in the learning curve with MSE is low ...

Comment: In the learning phase your model has overfitted to learning set - this means low MSE. On testing set you got high error rate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#Machine_learning

Comment: Thanks frankov. Checking your reference, I see that the number of boosting iterations is correct in my model (it is not learning for a long time, suffering overffiting by then), and that the test error in the second chart is less than 0.1 (does it seem too much?). I just see a strange behavior when the training error is almost 0 from the begining in the second chart ...

Answer (score 0):

If the process generating your datasets is non-stationary it could cause the behavior you describe. 
In that case the distribution of the dataset you're using to test has not been used for training